# What am I missing in the XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm completely new to the javascript and ajax world but trying to learn.

Right now I'm testing the XMLHttpRequest and I can't make work even the simplest example. This is the code I'm trying to run

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                    var container = document.getElementById('line');
                    container.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                }
            }  

            xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com', true);                  
            xhr.send(null); 
        }
    </script>
```

And I always get the alert with the status 0. I've read tons of webs about this and I don't know what am I missing. I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are running into the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Unless your code is actually running on www.google.com (which is unlikely), this is going to error.

Also, and while this isn't causing you a problem at the moment, it is poor practice and can lead to race conditions, you are using globals all over the place.

Make the xhr variable local to the function

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

And refer to it with `this` inside the `onreadstatechange` method.

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
// etc etc
```

Answer (score 8):

Following from [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482916/what-am-i-missing-in-the-xmlhttprequest/2482922#2482922):

You have to use a relative path to stay within the same origin policy. Otherwise most browsers will simply return an empty `responseText` and `status == 0`.

As one possible workaround, you could set up a very simple [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) if you are using Apache). This would allow you to use relative paths in your AJAX request, while the HTTP server would be acting as a proxy to any "remote" location.

The fundamental configuration directive to set up a reverse proxy in mod_proxy is the `ProxyPass`. You would typically use it as follows:

```
ProxyPass     /ajax/     http://google.com/
```

In this case, the browser would be requesting `/ajax/search?q=stack+overflow` but the server would serve this by acting as a proxy to `http://google.com/search?q=stack+overflow`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the same origin policy issue, your `alert` is in an illogical place. When you use XMLHttpRequest, the function assigned to `xhr.onreadystatechange` will be called whenever `readyState` changes. `readyState` should change (in theory) from 0 (initialized) to 1 (sent) to 2 (loading) to 3 (interactive) to 4 (finished).

What your code does is check  the `readyState` and see if the request is finished (`if (xhr.readyState == 4)`), and if not, `alert` the [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Since the request hasn't been sent yet (or has just been sent), there shouldn't be an HTTP status yet.

Ideally, you should move the `alert` inside the `if` block, so it lets you know when it finishes.