# JavaScript Same Origin Policy - How does it apply to different subdomains?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

How does the Same Origin Policy apply to the following two domains?

http://server1.MyDomain.com

http://server2.MyDomain.com

Can I run JS on a page hosted on server1, if the content is retreived from server2?

**edit** according to Daniel's answer below, I can include scripts between different subdomains using the `<script>` tag, but what about asynchronous requests? What if I download a script from server2 onto the page hosted on server1. Can I use the script to communicate asynchronously with a service on server2?

Comment: Mileage is going to vary a bit with IE, but the general rule is same host, same port for direct XHR. You can load scripts from wherever you choose but as far as async goes, JSONP script injection is your only option without a proxy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can only include scripts between different subdomains using the `<script>` tag, as it is exempt from the policy.

Using `http://www.example.com/dir/page.html` as source (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules)):

```
Compared URL                               Outcome  Reason
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://www.example.com/dir/page.html       Success  Same protocol and host
http://www.example.com/dir2/other.html     Success  Same protocol and host
http://www.example.com:81/dir2/other.html  Failure  Same protocol and host but different port
https://www.example.com/dir2/other.html    Failure  Different protocol
http://en.example.com/dir2/other.html      Failure  Different host
http://example.com/dir2/other.html         Failure  Different host (exact match required)
http://v2.www.example.com/dir2/other.html  Failure  Different host (exact match required)
```

**UPDATE:**

> Can I use the script to communicate
>   asynchronously with a service on
>   server2?

Yes, you can with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which takes advantage of the open policy for `<script>` tags to retrieve JSON from other origins.

You may also want to consider using a reverse proxy, as desribed in the following Stack Overflow post:

- [What am I missing in the XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482916/what-am-i-missing-in-the-xmlhttprequest/2482941#2482941)

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for the reply. I've edited the question with a follow up question. Any chance you could add your thoughts to it? Thanks

Comment: @Dave: You might want to check out JSONP. You may also want to consider setting up a reverse proxy, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482916/what-am-i-missing-in-the-xmlhttprequest/2482941#2482941

Comment: This is a great, thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can run any script that you insert on your never mind where it comes from. Think about how to insert a google map on your page.

What your describe is a pattern called jsonp. Where a server on a other host  returns a script  you insert in your page and the script calls a function in your page with the response arguments.