# How to solve JavaScript origin problem with an application and static file server

Tags: javascript, apache, mod-proxy, same-origin-policy

In a system that I'm building I want to serve

1. Static files (static HTML pages and a lot of images), and
2. Dynamic XML generated by my servlet.

The dynamic XML is generated from my database (through Hibernate) and I use Restlets to serve it in response to API calls. I want to create a static file server (e.g. Apache) so that this does not interfere with the dynamic server traffic. Currently both servers need to run on the **same** machine.

I've never done something like this before and this is where I'm stuck:

The static HTML pages contain JavaScript that makes API calls to the dynamic server. However, since the two servers operate on different ports, I get stuck with the same origin problem. How can this be solved?

As a bonus, if you can point me to any resources that explain how to create such a static/dynamic content serving system, I'll be happy.

Thanks!

Comment: Is putting both servers behind Tomcat a good idea? Then, Tomcat can direct the static and dynamic file requests to the appropriate servers. Also, all client requests will to the same IP address, so would that solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should setup mod_proxy in apache to forward dynamic requests to whatever backend server you are using. Your existing setup (ie. two separate ports) is perfect, you just need to tell apache 'proxy dynamic requests to my backend server without letting the browser know'.

This page should get you started - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Thanks sri. One question: If I do this, do I still implement the JSON approach, or does the same origin policy problem go away in this case?

Comment: It goes away. You will configure apache to proxy url patterns like /backend/* to your backend server. Because the browser doesn't know about two servers, same-origin policy problem goes away.

Comment: Great, I have installed Apache2 and mod_proxy, now working on this. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: YAY, **it works**. Small step for mankind, huge relief for me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to load a script tag from the Reslet server... have a look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543784/javascript-same-origin-policy-question)