# Loading A Page With Ajax- Without Jquery

Tags: javascript

Can someone please show me the basic syntax for loading a page via AJAX just using javascript-- not jquery? load() method?

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: a simple google search would give you a bunch of examples. Either way, it is quite a hassle, which is why people just use jquery or other libraries since it simplifies the whole process. here is a similar question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest

Comment: A good starting point would be to see how jQuery does it. Not to use it but to go to the actual source and read/observe how it's done there. It's a very good implementation, and the code is really clean.

Comment: @kennypu  That's the thing! Nothing but jquery load() examples in my search results. The dirty, old fashioned wayhas been buried, it seems...

Comment: @JoelEtherton My failings with jquery are the reason why I'm asking! Is the lesson at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp still relevant?

Comment: This is some good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @user1933397: If it comes from w3schools I'd stay away from it. Some of it's right, but some of it's misleading. It's better to use the mozilla documents suggested by bfavaretto.

Comment: @user1933397 if i literally search "XMLHttpRequest() tutorials" I get a bunch of relevant examples..

Comment: @kennypu  Thanks for pointing out a good google search  term,lol. "A well defined problem is half solved"...so they say...*palm to forehead*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will write more lines without jQuery, in jQuery it will done in 2 lines.

Anyway, here is the code

**without jQuery**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
   {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com', true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

if you want to do some POST stuffs

```
xmlhttp.open("POST",'http://www.google.com', true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

You also need to do checking for IE

see this link for more understanding - [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

**with jQuety**

```
$.get('http://www.google.com', function(responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});
```

Comment: I don't mind the extra work, but I now have a good starting point to put this in a nice wrapper function.