# GET xmlHTTPrequest not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to make an ajax commenting system where if a new comment is posted, the document title changes to (1) website title (like twitter)

my code is here

The xmlHTTPrequest

```
 function loadXMLDoc7(url)
        {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById('newcomments').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
```

The PHP

```
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    function auto2comments()
    { 
    var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('uiuiui');";
    echo "loadXMLDoc7(MyDiv1.innerHTML)";
    echo "}";
    echo "setInterval(\"auto2comments()\",15000);</script>";
    }
```

The DIV uiuiui contains /newcommentingi.php?show=0&id=username
The problem is when the Newcomments DIV gets filled, it shows
ID =
Show = 0
why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XmlHttpRequest object is asynchronous, which means that when it has the data ready, it returns it in a method. It is best to create a function to act as an event handler so that when the server responds, it calls the event handler function.

I think the solution you need is similar to here: [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)