# How to make get requests with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, get, request

My apologies if this is a trivial question but I couldn't find how to make requests using JavaScript.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://www.google.com");
alert(request.status);
```

I get 0, but http statuses should be between 100 and 600. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're never making the request. [See an example of XMLHttpRequest here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "http://www.google.com", true);
oReq.send();
```

Notice `oReq.send()`, which sends the request. Also notice the `reqListener` function, which gets called when the request completes.

Answer (score 2):

Check the article [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)

In a nutshell, XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous by default, so you need to register a callback function on the onreadystate.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200){
    alert(request.status);
    // To get the response use request.responseText;
  }
}
request.open("GET", "http://www.google.com");
request.send(null);
```

Note that for older versions of IE (IE5 and IE6), you need to get the request from an ActiveX Object as follows:

```
variable=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Comment: Please make an example to illustrate your answer. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you just define your request. Did you forget to send it ?

Try

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://www.google.com");
request.send(null);
alert(request.status);
```