# Javascript get JSON result of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the result of some XMLHttpRequest of Jenkins server

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var res = oReq.open("get", "http://" + IP + ":8080/job/Job1/lastBuild/api/json?depth=1", true);
oReq.send();
```

I am not getting the input to `var res` however, why is that?

**EDIT**

I tried one of the answers that were commented here and I am getting

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What does it means?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Read the documentation on the XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use jQuery's $.getJSON, $.ajax, $.get and etc.
But if You want native way (don't want to load external libraries or prefer native javascript and etc.) so try this:

```js
// returns proper XMLHttpRequest object
    function getXmlHttp(){
      var xmlhttp;
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
          xmlhttp = false;
        }
      }
      if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      return xmlhttp;
    }

    // creates CORS Request object
    function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
      var xhr = getXmlHttp();
      if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
      } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
      } else {
        xhr = null;
      }
      return xhr;
    }
    
    // does request and calls callback function and passes json data to callback function
    function getJson(url, callback) {
      var request = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
      if(!request) {
        console.log('Cannot create request');
        return false;
      }

      request.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        callback(data);
      };

      request.onerror = function() {
        console.log('Error happen');
      };

      request.send(null);
    }
    
    // usage
    //var url = "http://" + IP + ":8080/job/Job1/lastBuild/api/json?depth=1";
    var url = 'http://time.jsontest.com/?alloworigin=true';
    getJson(url, function(data) {
      alert(data.time);
      console.log(data);
    });
```

About CORS: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ 
Also: there must be defined access rules about CORS in web server with IP that You're requesting.
read about it here: http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html , http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

also You can add custom headers in serverside application.
for example in PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in RoR: https://gist.github.com/dhoelzgen/cd7126b8652229d32eb4

Comment: getting 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

Comment: getting Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'XMLHttpRequest': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Comment: what browser? and have You tried again after my update?

Comment: does it matter if I run in from localhost as debug?

Answer (score 1):

1) Use [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). It will help you with a lot of stuff!

```
$.getJSON( "http://" + IP + ":8080/job/Job1/lastBuild/api/json?depth=1", function( data ) {
    //data contains full parsed JavaScript object of json 
});
```

2) Access-Control-Allow-Origin allows the Browser to read informations from a other Origin, bur here is a better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: getting 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

Answer (score 0):

`open` doesn't return anything, check the [API reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Since you're making an async request by sending the third argument as `true`, it's not going to finish immediately after `send()` either. I'd recommend reading [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) on how to use XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `xhr.responseType = 'json';` and `response` will be a JSON.

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://echo.jsontest.com/insert-key-here/insert-value-here/key/value');
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    console.log('response', this.response); // JSON response  
  }
};
xhr.send();
```