# How to load Ruby-on-Rails webpage to Samsung Gear S2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tizen

Good Morning. I've been searching thoroughly and can't seem to find a similar question. The Tizen documentation seems to not be straightforward.

Suppose I have a Ruby-on-Rails application running on `localhost`, say at `192.168.1.3:3000`. How do I create a Tizen application on a Samsung Gear S2 device that would connect to the running server and fetch the webpage from there? Is this possible?

Comment: I've improved your formatting just a little. Also, while "thank you" is polite in real life, it's just extra noise here. Show your gratitude with upvotes instead. :)

Comment: @JasonMc92 Thank you very much. I'll upvote when I've enough reputation points. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use XMLHttpRequest.

For XMLHttpRequest tutorial you can see:

[How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)

http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

*Don't forget to add the required privileges.

*Also remember to connect your GS2 to the same router your localhost is connected to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Trying it out now. Will upvote when done. :)