# Setting the target of an onclick event to a specific location

Tags: php, html, onclick, target

I split my body content in two parts. The left one has a map and buttons. When I click on the button, I get the result from `Arad.php` in another window.

How can I set the target to the second half (split right) of my body?

```
<body> 
    <div class="split left">
        <div class="centered">    
            <h2>Button on Image</h2>
            <p>Add a button to an image:</p>
            <div class="container">
                <img src="Harta_Romaniei.jpg" alt="Harta_Romaniei" style="width:100%">
                <button class="btnarad"; onclick= "window.location.href='Arad.php'"; Target="split right">Arad</button>
                <button class="btntimisoara">Timisoara</button>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="split right">
      <div class="centered">
        <h2>Information</h2>

        // I want the information here!

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Whats PHP tag doing here?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have much to do with PHP, you should really do it with HTML + JavaScript.

The window.href.location will always redirect you to another route, and will never do what you want.

You'll need something like this: [Simple Load an HTML page from javascript based on window width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482015/simple-load-an-html-page-from-javascript-based-on-window-width)