# Include HTML file in a another HTML file without any javascript,php

Tags: html

Include HTML file in a  another HTML file without any javascript,php.

Im trying using jquery and Html Import also.it wont support for chrome and opera browsers

Please guide me?

Comment: use xmlHttpRequest, look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest

Comment: no javascript and no php.. so what do you want to use? the fantasy? jquery is javascript. I think you need to update your question. Moreover, if you want to use jquery, this is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure this is even possible with just html loading in another html page. easy fix but its php rename your file to name.php and just use an include statement in the html:

Comment: You can include the contents of one HTML page in another by loading it in an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).