# Javascript Change in HTML content not working

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am using an externally referenced Javascript file which is in the same directory as my HTML file.

My javascript program reads some data from a ".txt file" and stores them in variables speed,altitude & pressure. I wish to display the values of these variables in my HTML. But for some reason this is still not working.

Javascript Code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
  var content = data;
  console.log(content);


  var obj = JSON.parse(content);
  var speed = obj.speed_json;
  console.log(speed);
  var altitude = obj.altitude_json;
  console.log(altitude);
  var pressure = obj.pressure_json;
  console.log(pressure);
});

document.getElementById("pressurehtml").innerHTML = altitude;
document.getElementById("speedhtml").innerHTML = speed;
document.getElementById("altitudehtml").innerHTML = pressure;
```

HTML Code:

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h1 id="pressurehtml">Pressure</h1>
  <h1 id="altitudehtml">Altitude</h1>
  <h1 id="speedhtml">Speed</h1>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using nodejs `fs` library. You cannot read files like this from the browser

Comment: Can you explain further..

Comment: Add jQuery and change `fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', function(error, data) {` to `$.get('data.txt', function(data) {`

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code you are using is NodeJS, there is no `require` or `fs` in normal JavaScript. To read your file, try using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Javascript which will create an ajax request to load your JSON.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.txt',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var speed = data.speed_json;
    var altitude = data.altitude_json;
    var pressure = data.pressure_json;

    // Append to HTML
    document.getElementById("pressurehtml").innerHTML = altitude;
    document.getElementById("speedhtml").innerHTML = speed;
    document.getElementById("altitudehtml").innerHTML = pressure;
  }
});
```

Also be sure to add jquery to your html `<head>`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do i add the jquery to my HTML?

Comment: @JonathanPereira see my updated answer. I added how to add jquery at the end of my post

Comment: What should be the code added to the HTML file? @Z-Bone.

Comment: @JonathanPereira this: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>` under the <head>

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a server-side [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) module in the browser.  While node.js and web browsers both use javascript, the environments are different. In this case, you're trying to use the node `fs` module, which is not available in the browser environment.

The most common way to read a file in the browser environment is to make an HTTP request.  Z-Bone's answer is a good example using JQuery, here's one that only uses the XMLHttpRequest object with no external dependencies:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'data.txt', true);

req.onreadystatechange = function(error) {
  if (req.readyState === 4) {
    if (req.status === 200) {
      var content = req.responseText;
      console.log(content);

      var obj = JSON.parse(content);
      var speed = obj.speed_json;
      console.log(speed);
      var altitude = obj.altitude_json;
      console.log(altitude);
      var pressure = obj.pressure_json;
      console.log(pressure);

      document.getElementById("pressurehtml").innerHTML = altitude;
      document.getElementById("speedhtml").innerHTML = speed;
      document.getElementById("altitudehtml").innerHTML = pressure;

    } else {
      console.error(req.statusText);
    }
  }
};

req.send();
```

Note that `data.txt` must be served out through a webserver.  If you're trying to do this locally using the file:// handler this will not work due to browser CORS settings.

For more info:

[How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started