# How to use XMLHttpRequest in JScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, exe

I'm using JSC provided by Microsoft (Dot Net Framework) to convert JavaScript code into executable Windows application. So, is how should I get echo response from PHP file stored on Server, as we were using,

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

So, how should I use this in JScript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

```js
var req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Comment: Please add a little more details