# Javascript - Leaflet markers not showing

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, marker

I've been trying to find solutions for this basic problem without any success.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  showMap()
})
var map;
function showMap() {
        map = L.map('mapid').setView([45.508991, -73.568602], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
          maxZoom: 12,
          id: 'mapbox.streets',
          accessToken: 'sk.eyJ1IjoidGlydmF4IiwiYSI6ImNqNWJ3cHdnazAzeDUyd25xMThzZXc0b3kifQ.NRP_9hz5G4k0xQAwIje5bw'
        }).addTo(map);
        var marker = L.marker([45.508991, -73.568602]).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup("<b>Batiment PK</b><br>Depart</br>").openPopup();
}
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var coords = feature.geometry.coordinates;
        //window.alert(coords);
        var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
        var marker1 = L.marker(markerLocation);
        map.addLayer(marker1);


}
function printLocationOnMap(location){
    var loc = JSON.parse(location);

    L.geoJson(loc, {
        onEachFeature : onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map)
}
function search(debut, fin, rayon) {
   var url = "http://localhost:8080//activites-375e?du=" + debut + "&au=" + fin + "&rayon=" + rayon + "&lat=45.508991&lng=-73.568602";
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("GET", url, false);
    client.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/json");
    client.send(null);
    if (client.status == 200){
        printLocationOnMap(client.responseText);
    }
    else{
        alert("Oups, ça n'a pas fonctionner. \n statut : " + client.status + " " + client.statusText + "\n");
    }
    return false;
}
```

The parameter location in printLocationOnMap is a geoJson. (it is valide and huge but here is a sample) :

```
{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[45.48753749999999,-73.8837685],"type":"Point"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Parc","province": "blabla", ......}}],"type":"FeatureCollection"}
```

This code works without errors.
In the function showMap(), the marker is working well and the popup too. But impossible to make the onEachFeature() function work properly. I saw that touching the leaflet css may work so i've tried this, but still not working...

In fact the most frustrating is that when the function printLocationOnMap() is finished i can see for a 1/4 of a second the markers but they immediatly disappear then.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You should share how you call `printLocationOnMap` and in particular a sample of the value you pass as `location` argument.

Comment: @ghybs i've just edited the post. Is it clearer? I really cant manage to understant because i can see the damn marker but for less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

1. You seem to miss the callback implementation step when using `XMLHttpRequest`. See [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)
2. The GeoJSON response sample you provide seems to use `[latitude, longitude]` order in `coordinates`, whereas it should be `[longitude, latitude]` to be compliant with GeoJSON specification. This might be the reason why you have to build a new marker in your `onEachFeature` function, whereas it should have been already done automatically when using `L.geoJSON`. Because your coordinates order is reversed, the marker is drawn somewhere in Antarctica instead of Montreal, Canada.
3. As for your marker being visible very briefly before disappearing, it is very strange indeed and might be due to how you call your `search` function. But bad use of `XMLHttpRequest` (point 1) might also play a role.

Comment: I just changed the order of lat and long and it doesn't change the problem but thank you for noticing ;). The XMLHttpRequest doesn't seem the problem to me. I made some windows.alert() on the geojson and javascript receives it well i think...

Comment: I just realised i have two warnings of this king : [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. leaflet:l6. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: I had to put in <form> th following : <form onsubmit="return false;" > It is finally working