# How do I embed an API call in my index.html file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to work out how to embed an API call response into my `index.html` file in order to update a website counter using JavaScript.

I have tried multiple blogs and YouTube tutorials but as I'm not experienced with JS I am really struggling.

Here is my API:
`https://b9hsa93hif.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/`

Here is my attempted `script.js` file:

```
const countEl = document.getElementById('count');

updateVisitCount();

function updateVisitCount() {
    fetch('https://b9hsa93hif.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        countEl.innerHTML = res.value;
    })
}
```

As my API updates automatically each time the page is refreshed, I presume I do not need the JavaScript function itself to count - but I don't know how to rewrite it correctly.

Here is the snippet from my attempted `index.html` file:

```
</div>  
  <p>This page was viewed</p>
  <h1 id="count"></h1>
  <p>times</p>
```

I would like my static webpage to display `This page was viewed [return result of API call] times`.

Thanks in advance!

**--UPDATE--**

I have managed to resolve this, thanks for the contributions **@Barmar** as they steered me in the right direction, and updating the `res.value` to `res.clicks` was an essential step.

However, the main issue was the fact that my API is linked to API Gateway and a Lambda function, and I was missing some key code in there. I realised this when trying to enable CORS on the API Gateway resource, and in searching for help I found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832288/aws-api-gateway-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present). One of the comments in there had the correct code to include in the Lambda function (I've marked it between >>> <<<):

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    >>>'headers': {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },<<<
    'body': json.dumps({'clicks': int(ddbResponse['Attributes']['clicks'])})
```

When I updated that in my Lambda function, and refreshed the website based on my updated `index.html` file, it worked correctly.

Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console? Like something related to CORS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display API request results in HTML page using only js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770892/display-api-request-results-in-html-page-using-only-js)

Comment: @Barmar I'm using Codepen and not getting any CORS errors, it's just not displaying the API response

Comment: @AuqibRather thanks for the suggestion, I can't work out how to apply the JS in that answer to my own use case, as it contains things like ```var price_USD = document.getElementById('price-usd');```

Comment: `res.value` should be `res.clicks`

Comment: thanks @Barmar, I will try that too. I'm not sure who voted down my question, but as this is only the second question I've asked, I'd be keen to know where I could do better

Comment: Is your HTML page also stored on the same AWS server?

Comment: Do you actually get the words `[return result of API call]`?

Comment: @Barmar yes the HTML page is stored on the same AWS server and no I don't get the words ```[return result of API call]```. I want to get the number of clicks returned from the API call

Comment: I know what you want to get, I'm trying to understand what you're getting instead.

Comment: Did you change `res.value` to `res.clicks`?

Comment: Yes I changed it in Codepen, but still get a blank value back

Comment: Make sure the script is at the end of the HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 0):

you have to change code to

```js
fetch('https://b9hsa93hif.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(res => {

// do something

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = res.clicks;   //you used of clicks parameter

//do something

});
```

```html
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Comment: thanks @mohammad soleimanpour. when I try that in Codepen, I get ```This page was viewed [blank] times```. Is that normal? Would I have to actually upload the new index.html file and JavaScript file to see the result?

Comment: @fhoskyns Check the console. I get the error `Access to fetch at 'https://b9hsa93hif.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: @Barmar, which console are you using? I'm not even sure how to check this in a console. Very new to coding

Comment: In Chrome use `View -> Developer -> Javascript Console`

Comment: @Barmar I see - so you think I should change the CORS settings in AWS?

Comment: No, you don't need CORS if the HTML and API are in the same domain.

Comment: @fhoskyns yes, you have to upload the ńew index.html file, in order to get rid of the CORS error.