# How to make HTTPREQUEST with authorization and accept header?

Tags: javascript, html, api

Here is the documentation for the api:

```
curl -g "https://api.com" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $api-key" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json"
```

Here's what I have. And its not working. Please help. Any advice would be really appreciated it. I am new to web development but really enjoy it.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();


    request.open("GET", "https://api.com", false);
   request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9");
    requset.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json");
    request.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    var thetables = document.getElementById("Main");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(namez);
    cell1.appendChild(cellText)
    var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
    var cellText1 = document.createTextNode(response[0]);
    cell2.appendChild(cellText1)
    var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
    var cellText2 = document.createTextNode(response[1]);
    cell3.appendChild(cellText2)
    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);
    row.appendChild(cell3)
    thetables.appendChild(row);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: `setRequestHeader` should be after `open`

Comment: ok but theres no typo in my actual code.

Comment: Ok i fixed everything that you guys suggested no luck.

Comment: Why was this down voted? She provided a legit code example, and the question is legit.

Comment: Why require authentication when it is hard coded in Javascript?

Comment: You have to signup and they give you an api key to use.

Comment: can you open the network panel of your browser and make sure the request is send properly?

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader for the usage of "setRequestHeader".
You need to pass 2 params, not only one stirng. I.e:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9");
```

Comment: I fixed it but no luck.