# How to call Other Application API from Script in Service-Now

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I write some API using Django in Python, I want to call this API's from service now **from script**.

I try to call my API using **jQuery** but it is not wokring for me, i search on net they said use **$j** as jQuery in **service-now** but it is also not working.

i want to test My API's, it is working fine or not.

Please tell me or correct me if i missing any step or any one knows how i implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use vanilla javascript. If you're making the call from the client, this should work:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Take a look at this thread: [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)