# jQuery ajaxForm uploadProgress preventing flask render_template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, ajaxform

I created a progressBar in my flask application which, on the front end, does the following:

```
$(function () {
        $('form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                uploadPercentage = percentComplete;
            }
        });
    });
```

Somehow, this is preventing the following return at the end of my post route in flask from working
`return render_template('channel_match.html', data=config_data)`

Really not sure why this is the case and haven't found much via google. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out via ["return render_template()" doesn't work [XMLHttpRequest() & flask]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60053443/return-render-template-doesnt-work-xmlhttprequest-flask)

Fix was to add the following to my ajaxForm

```
        success: function (res) {
            document.write(res);
        }
```