# How to iterate through a JSON file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following Javascript file:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettopartists&user=USERNAMEHERE&api_key=APIKEYHERE=json', true)
request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  let data = JSON.parse(this.response);

  if(request.status == 200){

    for(let artist in data){
      console.log(artist.name);
    }

  } else {
    console.log('Failure to connect. Please verify username and try again.');
  }

}

request.send()
```

That code prints out 'undefined' in the console when I really want it to print out each artists name.

Here is an example of the JSON file:

```
{
  "topalbums": {
    "album": [
      {
        "artist": {
          "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/City+and+Colour",
          "name": "City and Colour",
          "mbid": ""
        },
        "@attr": {
          "rank": "1"
        },
        "image": [
          {
            "size": "small",
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/dc4fdb888cf796679cfe421ca9bc5317.jpg"
          },
          {
            "size": "medium",
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/dc4fdb888cf796679cfe421ca9bc5317.jpg"
          },
          {
            "size": "large",
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/dc4fdb888cf796679cfe421ca9bc5317.jpg"
          },
          {
            "size": "extralarge",
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/dc4fdb888cf796679cfe421ca9bc5317.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "playcount": "69",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/City+and+Colour/Little+Hell+(Deluxe)",
        "name": "Little Hell (Deluxe)",
        "mbid": ""
      },
      {
        "artist": {
          "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Various+Artists",
          "name": "Various Artists",
          "mbid": "4e46dd54-81a6-4a75-a666-d0e447861e3f"
        },
        "@attr": {
          "rank": "2"
        },
        "image": [
          {
            "size": "small",
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/d1ce625570a8d54f2af4da3decbf901c.jpg"
          },
          {
            "size": "medium",
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/d1ce625570a8d54f2af4da3decbf901c.jpg"
          },
          {
            "size": "large",
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/d1ce625570a8d54f2af4da3decbf901c.jpg"
          },
          {
            "size": "extralarge",
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/d1ce625570a8d54f2af4da3decbf901c.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "playcount": "46",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Various+Artists/1+Am.+Study+Session",
        "name": "1 Am. Study Session",
        "mbid": ""
      },
```

What I want to happen is to have the name of each artist printed in the console. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Thank you for your time and if there is anything I can add for clarity, please don't hesitate.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: `for (let album of data.topalbums.album)` (notice the use of `of` instead of `in`, and the dot notation to access the `album` Array in the data). And then `console.log(album.artist.name)`

Comment: Can you clarify- is that JSON example an actual example of the response from your request? I ask because it seems to be returning Top Albums, and your URL mentions "top artists": 
`http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettopartists&user=USERNAMEHERE&api_key=APIKEYHERE=json`

Comment: @blex thank you! Worked perfectly. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the JSON file you gave. This entire object is what you have in `data`. It's as if you wrote this directly:

```
let data = { "topalbums": { ... } };
```

If you had this kind of object, you can't skip directly to the array three levels deep. JavaScript doesn't know you want to go down a few levels, iterate over `album`, and pull only each `artist` object from each element in the array. You need to write all these things explicitly. You also want to use `for..of` to iterate over array values, as `for..in` will only get you keys (like 0, 1, 2, etc). Here's an example:

```js
let data = {"topalbums":{"album":[{"artist":{"url":"https://www.last.fm/music/City+and+Colour","name":"City and Colour","mbid":""},"@attr":{"rank":"1"},"image":[{"size":"small","#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/dc4fdb888cf796679cfe421ca9bc5317.jpg"},{"size":"medium","#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/dc4fdb888cf796679cfe421ca9bc5317.jpg"},{"size":"large","#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/dc4fdb888cf796679cfe421ca9bc5317.jpg"},{"size":"extralarge","#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/dc4fdb888cf796679cfe421ca9bc5317.jpg"}],"playcount":"69","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/City+and+Colour/Little+Hell+(Deluxe)","name":"Little Hell (Deluxe)","mbid":""},{"artist":{"url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Various+Artists","name":"Various Artists","mbid":"4e46dd54-81a6-4a75-a666-d0e447861e3f"},"@attr":{"rank":"2"},"image":[{"size":"small","#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/d1ce625570a8d54f2af4da3decbf901c.jpg"},{"size":"medium","#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/d1ce625570a8d54f2af4da3decbf901c.jpg"},{"size":"large","#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/d1ce625570a8d54f2af4da3decbf901c.jpg"},{"size":"extralarge","#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/d1ce625570a8d54f2af4da3decbf901c.jpg"}],"playcount":"46","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Various+Artists/1+Am.+Study+Session","name":"1 Am. Study Session","mbid":""}]}};

for(let album of data.topalbums.album){
  console.log(album.artist.name);
}
```