# js access to object JSON from url

Tags: javascript, json

in some case i want to show a specific object of JSON file which is load from url in js :

```html
<div id="me2"></div>
<script>
function Get(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}
var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get('https://www.instagram.com/barkobco/?__a=1'));
document.getElementById("me2").innerHTML = json_obj.graphql.user.edge_follow;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but the output is : [object Object]

why?

the correct object value is : 25

Comment: The code presented does not perform a request in the correct manner. See [MDN's article on the topic for examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the count, you'll have to go 1 more level:

```html
<div id="me2"></div>
<script>
function Get(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}
var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get('https://www.instagram.com/barkobco/?__a=1'));
document.getElementById("me2").innerHTML = json_obj.graphql.user.edge_follow.count;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `json_obj.graphql.user.edge_follow` is still an object you need to find `.count` of it.

```html
<div id="me2"></div>
<script>
function Get(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}
var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get('https://www.instagram.com/barkobco/?__a=1'));
console.log(json_obj)
document.getElementById("me2").innerHTML = json_obj.graphql.user.edge_follow.count;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```