# JavaScript: alert XHR response?

Tags: javascript, html, http, xmlhttprequest, alert

I'm trying to `alert();` the response for a webpage. But the alert popup is blank. The HTTP request returns status 200 and I can see the response HTML in the browser console Network tab.

I've tried examples shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest). The alert window is always blank...

What am I getting wrong here? (I'm new to JS).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "https://website.com/page", true);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.send();
        
        alert(xhr.response);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to wait for the XHR to load first

Comment: thanks, can you provide an example of what that's supposed to look like?

Comment: Start with the documentation of `XMLHttpRequest`. Also not hard to find tutorials on using it