# XMLHttpRequest body empty although same origin

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I am accessing `https://example.com/about/edit` (Domain changed for privacy reasons) from my browser.
There, I have JavaScript code running that is sending a HTTP request to `https://example.com/about/api/id` with an identifier for an object on my server.

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://example.com/api/"+id, true)
xhr.send(null)
console.log(xhr.responseText) // <empty string>
```

The interesting thing is that `xhr.responseText` is empty, though I can see it in my Firefox network tab and also the request is from the same origin.

[Photo from firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oubxi.png)

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: As you code do not wait for the response, Take a glance this will help you, [Get Response By XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)